# How to fix '404 Object not found' in apache-php environment?

Tags: php, apache, server, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I have to transfer my website to another hosting service. The total size of website(created zip) is 7.9GB and I tried using ftp_nb_put() function to transfer the zip with set_time_limit(0) on the script. But, on executing the php script the page waits for some time and then throws a '404 Object not found'. When I checked my other server I observed that a zip file of 2.09GB was created. Plz help me what should I do?

P.S. : I tried splitting the file but got same 404 error after some time. (Got approx 2 files of 2GB then timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run long-term PHP processes in Apache SAPI. Use CLI SAPI instead. In other words, run your script in command line interface, e.g.:

```
php -dmemory_limit=4g script.php
```

However, I find it easier to transfer a file with a command line utility such as [`ftp`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/FTP-3.html)